# In App Purchase with fingerprint or Face ID in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, xcode11, face-id

I have an Objective-C Project which I am working using Xcode 11 and I am trying to implement In-App Purchase.
I used some tutorials and implemented successfully but I am not able to use Fingerprint or Face ID.

Please find the Image Url below in which it shows an old subscription interface asking for the password.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The interface used for purchases (shown your screen shot) belongs to Apple, not you. You cannot affect it in any way.

Note too that what you see while testing in the sandbox is not at all what a real user will see in the published app. So the screen shot really indicates nothing about whether the user will see the fingerprint / Face ID dialog.